# How to refresh certain Ranges asynchronously generated by a query of Power Query in Excel with VBA？

Tags: excel, vba, asynchronous, refresh, powerquery

There are posts in Stack Overflow that indicate how to:

- Refresh all queries asynchronously
- Refresh some queries one by one (i.e. not asynchronously)

How do I refresh certain ranges (*for example, given an array of those ranges' name*) asynchronously generated by a query of Power Query in Excel with VBA and execute subsequent sentences in VBA after detecting those asynchronous refreshes are done.

Ways I've tried include:

```vb
Sub fail_1()
'This method cannot guarantee showing the msgbox at the end of this sub AFTER the two ranges are refreshed
    arrRngName = Array("rng1","rng2")
    For Each itm in arrRngName
        Range(itm).ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
    Next itm
    MsgBox "All the refreshes are done asynchronously" 'This is an example of the subsequent sentence
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub fail_2()
'This method cannot guarantee neither that showing the msgbox at the end of this sub AFTER the two ranges are refreshed
    arrRngName = Array("rng1","rng2")
    For Each itm in arrRngName
        With ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - " & itm).OLEDBConnection
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .Refresh
        End With
    Next itm
    MsgBox "All the refreshes are done asynchronously" 'This is an example of the subsequent sentence
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub fail_3()
'This method can guarantee showing the msgbox at the end of this sub AFTER the two ranges are refreshed, but it cannot refresh ALL the ranges at the same time(asynchronously)
   arrRngName = Array("rng1","rng2")
   For Each itm in arrRngName
        With ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - " & itm).OLEDBConnection
            .BackgroundQuery = False
            .Refresh
        End With
   Next itm
   MsgBox "All the refreshes are done asynchronously" 'This is an example of the subsequent sentence
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry to have grammar mistakes in the title. It should be: How to refresh CERTAIN Ranges asynchronously generated by a query of Power Query in Excel with VBA？

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are no events that can be trapped with an `OLEDBConnection` object, so you will need to devise your own method.

There are two easy options:

**1. AfterCalculate**

If you have a table on your sheet that is modified by the Query, then you can handle the `AfterCalculate` event, as shown below:

*In ThisWorkbook module*

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mApp As Application
Private mIsManualRefresh As Boolean
Public Sub AwaitManualRefreshComplete()
    mIsManualRefresh = True
    If mApp Is Nothing Then Set mApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub mApp_AfterCalculate()
    If mIsManualRefresh Then
        mIsManualRefresh = False
        Debug.Print "Manual refresh complete (after calculate)."
    End If
End Sub
```

*and then in a Module:*

```
Public Sub RunMe1()
    Dim arrRngName As Variant
    Dim itm As Variant
    Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
    
    arrRngName = Array("qryAges", "qryGender", "Merge")
    
    ThisWorkbook.AwaitManualRefreshComplete
    For Each itm In arrRngName
        Set conn = ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - " & itm)
        With conn.OLEDBConnection
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .Refresh
        End With
        Debug.Print "Refresh " & conn.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

**2. OnTime**

Use a timer to test the `Refreshing` property on your `OLEDBConnection`

*In a Module:*

```
Public Sub RunMe2()
    Dim arrRngName As Variant
    Dim itm As Variant
    Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
    
    arrRngName = Array("qryAges", "qryGender", "Merge")
    For Each itm In arrRngName
        Set conn = ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - " & itm)
        With conn.OLEDBConnection
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .Refresh
        End With
        Debug.Print "Refresh " & conn.Name
    Next
    AwaitManualRefreshComplete arrRngName
End Sub

Public Sub AwaitManualRefreshComplete(Optional arr As Variant)
    Static arrRngName As Variant
    Dim itm As Variant
    Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim isRefreshComplete As Boolean
    
    If Not IsMissing(arr) Then
        arrRngName = arr
    End If
    
    isRefreshComplete = True
    For Each itm In arrRngName
        Set conn = ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - " & itm)
        If conn.OLEDBConnection.Refreshing Then
            isRefreshComplete = False
        End If
    Next
    
    If Not isRefreshComplete Then
        Application.OnTime _
            EarliestTime:=Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), _
            Procedure:="AwaitManualRefreshComplete"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Debug.Print "Manual refresh complete (after time)."
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! The ontime method works just fine! Thx a lot!
But I haven't made the aftercalculate method clear. Which sentence triggers the detection of having finished the refresh?

Comment: Great. Please close the question if you are satisfied with the answer. Thanks.

Comment: There are some unsolved...

Comment: Dear Ambie, I just found that it runs into a strange situation that if I insert one or more sentense(s) after "AwaitManualRefreshComplete arrRngName" in the sub "RunMe2", it seems that AwaitManualRefreshComplete becomes ineffective, i.e., VBA will skip it and execute the next sentence.

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem. VBA can't skip lines of code, so I suggest you step through the code and see where the code goes.

Comment: Maybe the refresh goes too fast? Just try this to test whether `AwaitManualRefreshComplete arrRngName` in the sub `RunMe2` is skipped: Firstly, change the line `Debug.Print "Manual refresh complete (after time)."` in sub `AwaitManualRefreshComplete` into `MsgBox "AwaitManualRefreshComplete ends"`. Secondly, add one line just before `End Sub` in sub `RunMe2`: `MsgBox "RunMe ends"`. I found that there is just one MsgBox with the prompt "RunMe ends" shows up, but the other one didn't.